# Content Builder, pasting is GUI (from Notepad) adds font tags

Tags: marketing-cloud, content-builder

Even in the HTML tab, if I paste something copied from Notepad or another editor, a new `<font></font>` is placed in the code, and my original font-tag's attributes are removed.

**Orginal:**

```
<font style="font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#000000;">Here's the original content.</font>
```

**After copy-pasting:**

```
<font>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</font>
```

Comment: Anyone? This is a horrible user experience for people using the GUI, but also does the same thing in the HTML tab, so it's a bug in my opinion.

Comment: Have you tried reporting this to SF Support?

Answer (score 0):

This worked fine for me when I tried it. It is worth noting that the `font` tag is obsolete and not valid HTML5, in addition to the example using font with a `style` attribute instead of a `face`, `size`, or `color` attribute (the three proper attributes of a `font` tag before it became obsolete). Depending on the leniency of the web browser being used, it could be ignored or stripped out.

Have you tried using the same `style` attribute, in a `span` or `p` or otherwise valid tag to test?

Comment: Are you using "Content Builder" NOT"Classic Content"? I've tried span and p tags, yes. When you paste in copy, the app creates font tags. I know the font tag is obsolete, but within this app, Salesforce Marketing Cloud/ExactTarget, the app is creating the font tags, so I'm working with how the app creates copy. Thanks for the thoughts.